# Is angularjs a good fit for large datacentric enterprise web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a web application which will have many different pages. each page mainly shows data in table and various graphs based on data.

I want to decouple front end completely from the backend. for this reason I am considering angularjs. 
My concern is following two points:

- angular js is considered best for SPA style applications
- angularjs will load the partial view when required and will load data through ajax, every page needs at least two seperate http requests to render the page.

Is it really a good choice to select angular or any better approach?

Comment: No, I think angular would be bad for large data application, due to its dirty checking

Comment: If there is no further interaction with the user e.g. Just showing data and graphs I would recommend against angular. It's a great library but from what I understand from your question it will complicate your application with no clear benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that using Angular is a good solution, I am working in a very big project, that manage a lot of data and angular is working perfectly.

There are a lot of [advantages of using Angular](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-awesome-angularjs-features--net-25651). However, I think that it depends on your needs, if you don't need a rich experience of user, maybe you can select other option different from a SPA that could be faster, if you don’t have experience developing a SPA..

I think that in your case, it is most important choosing well the backend technology than the frontend technology, because the responsibility of managing the data is from the backend.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Angular JS is a good for these kind of applications.

1.) Angular JS simplifies your code.
2.) It builds on HTML so you don't have to learn something entirely new and it is fast to catch up.
3.) It has a large community so you can get help on topics easily.
4.) It is continuously evolving.
5.) It is based on MVC structure.

P.S: Read on dirty checking part of angular as it is considered best in some scenarios and not so good in others. It is considered to keep no. of objects to 1000 or less while using angular for good performance.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I would say yes, is good. But maybe you can see with your eyes some case studies and applications built with angular: [builtwith.angularjs.org](http://builtwith.angularjs.org/).

Check this blog post also: [Building large apps with AngularJS](https://coderwall.com/p/y0zkiw).

Comment: maximum applications built with angularjs doesnt have many different pages which is reverse of my case. so every page will casue two consecutive request for template and data. I am afraid, user experience may be slower